# Is there a way adding Freshworks chat widget to a website built on Gatsby?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chat, gatsby, react-helmet

Some chat software providers have Gatsby plugin available, or their provided script works without issues when included in html.js using React Helmet. However, some (Freshworks, for example) provide a script that gives 'unexpected token' and 'expression excepted' errors.
My question is whether there is a simple way to alter the code to make it work or not?

The code below includes a chat widget script provided by Freshworks that is included in Helmet before closing body tag.

```
 <Helmet>
        <script>
  function initFreshChat() {
    window.fcWidget.init({
      token: "5df26417-e127-480b-a0ff-d21908f5030f",
      host: "https://wchat.eu.freshchat.com"
    });
  }
  function initialize(i,t){var e;i.getElementById(t)?initFreshChat():((e=i.createElement("script")).id=t,e.async=!0,e.src="https://wchat.eu.freshchat.com/js/widget.js",e.onload=initFreshChat,i.head.appendChild(e))}function initiateCall(){initialize(document,"freshchat-js-sdk")}window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",initiateCall,!1):window.attachEvent("load",initiateCall,!1);
</script>
        </Helmet>
      </body>
```

Here's the error that was given after building the site.

```
Building static HTML failed

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  133 | //
  134 | // But on the command line of a file system, it's not as complicated, you can't
> 135 | // `cd` from a file, only directories.  This way, links have to know less about
      | ^
  136 | // their current path. To go deeper you can do this:
  137 | //
  138 | //     <Link to="deeper"/>


  WebpackError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/dist/utils/babel-loader.js):

  - utils.js:135 
    node_modules/@reach/router/lib/utils.js:135:1

  - typeof.js:11
    node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof.js:11:1

  - utils.js:23
    node_modules/@reach/router/lib/utils.js:23:1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use backticks (`` ` ``) inside your  component and wrap it inside curly braces (`{}`):

```
<Helmet>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        {`  function initFreshChat() {
    window.fcWidget.init({
      token: "5df26417-e127-480b-a0ff-d21908f5030f",
      host: "https://wchat.eu.freshchat.com"
    });
  }
  function initialize(i,t){var e;i.getElementById(t)?initFreshChat():((e=i.createElement("script")).id=t,e.async=!0,e.src="https://wchat.eu.freshchat.com/js/widget.js",e.onload=initFreshChat,i.head.appendChild(e))}function initiateCall(){initialize(document,"freshchat-js-sdk")}window.addEventListener?window.addEventListener("load",initiateCall,!1):window.attachEvent("load",initiateCall,!1);
        `}
     </script>
</Helmet>
```

Comment: Thank you, Ferran, for your fast and to the point answer. Everything works now.